# A ton of input at the login appears to lock the machine?

Tags: login, keyboard, freeze

Occasionally my one year old son will come into my office where my machine is at the command line login prompt. As my little geekling is wont, he starts banging on the keyboard like Daddy does.

As there is no one in the office to hit <kbd>^C</kbd> for him, eventually he writes the works of Shakespeare in the `hostname login:` prompt. At some point the machine gives up.

I will come back and you cannot <kbd>^C</kbd>, no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Or <kbd>F2</kbd> or anything else. I'm *fairly* certain that even ssh hangs and the only way to get the machine back is with a hard powercycle.

Is there anything *inside* the computer that I can do to prevent this from happening? Obviously the "easy" solution is to unplug the keyboard or move it somewhere else or put a lock on my office door. But I'd rather not do that, cause I kinda like encouraging him to type.

Plus it's a Model M so I'm not worried in the least that he'll damage it.

So what can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>?

You could switch to an inactive virtual console with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for example.